# Need assistance with java morse code translator

Tags: java

I have a Java translator which works when I translate from English to Morse but not from Morse to English.
If you could tell me what I need to do to make it translate morse that would be great. When I go from morse to english after I enter my morse code it just ends the program instead of giving me the translation.

Here is my code.

```
public class project1 {

public static void main ( String [] args ) {

char [] english = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0' };

String [] morse = { ".-" , "-..." , "-.-." , "-.." , "." , "..-." , "--." , "...." , ".." , ".---" , "-.-" , ".-.." , "--" , "-." , "---" , ".--." , "--.-" ,  ".-." , "..." , "-" , "..-" , "...-" , ".--" , "-..-" , "-.--" , "--.." , "|" };
    String a = Input.getString ( "Please enter MC if you want to translate Morse Code into English, or Eng if you want to translate from English into Morse Code" );
if (a.equals("MC"))
    {
        String b = Input.getString ("Please enter a sentence in Morse Code. Separate each letter/digit with a single space and delimit multiple words with a | .");    

        String[] words = b.split("|");
        for (String word: words )
        {
            String[] characters = word.split(" ");
            for (String character: characters) 
            {
                if (character.isEmpty()) { continue; }
        for (int m = 0; m < b.length(); m++)
                {
                    if (character.equals("inputMorseCode[m]"))    
                        System.out.print(english[ m ]);    
                }    
            }
            System.out.print(" ");    
        }    
    }
else if (a.equals("Eng"))
    {
        String c = Input.getString ( "Please enter a sentence in English, and separate each word with a blank space." );

        c = c.toLowerCase ();

        for ( int x = 0; x < english.length; x++ )
        {
            for ( int y = 0; y < c.length (); y++ )
            {
                if ( english [ x ] == c.charAt ( y ) )

                System.out.print ( morse [ x ] + "  " );


            }

        }


    }

    else 
   {
       System.out.println ( "Invalid Input" );

    }

}
}
```

Comment: add some more details and define problem you are facing...

Comment: try changing split condition in this line: String[] characters = word.split(" "); to that: String[] characters = word.split(""); But i'd rather write my own function which makes char array than use .split

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, change this

```
    for (int m = 0; m < b.length(); m++)
            {
                if (character.equals("inputMorseCode[m]"))    
                    System.out.print(english[ m ]);    
            }
```

to

```
    for (int m = 0; m < morse.length; m++)
            {
                if (character.equals(morse[m]))    
                    System.out.print(english[m]);    
            }
```

Since you are supposed to search the morse letter in the morse array.

That said, your code would be much more efficient if you create a `Map<String,Character>` and `Map<Character,String>` that Map morse Strings to English Characters and vice versa. They would replace your morse and english arrays, and will allow you to find the mapping of an English or Morse letter in constant time.

Comment: when i do this i get                                                                                     error: cannot find symbol                                                                                       for (int m = 0; m < morse.length(); m++)

Comment: @eliwinston Sorry for the typo. It should be `morse.length`

Comment: i did the change and compiles but when i enter the morse code it gives the wrong answer                                                                                                       i put . . . . in the program witch should display H it instead displays e e e e as if it was translating each charicter as its own word how whould i fix this?  thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

1. Your counter is on the wrong thing: `for (int m = 0; m < b.length(); m++)` should be `for (int m = 0; m < morse.length; m++)` so you're limited by the number of characters in the alphabet, not the number of characters input by the user.
2. You're not comparing the character to a morse character, you're comparing it to the string `"inputMorseCode[m]"`.  Change `if (character.equals("inputMorseCode[m]"))` to `if (character.equals(morse[m]))`